# How to execute more than CMakeLists.txt files in android

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I have two c++ libraries included in my project, and each has CMakeLists.txt file. What should I add in my `build.gradle` file to execute them ? I tried the following but it's not working:

```
cmake {
    path "CMakeLists.txt"
    path "src/main/cpp/fluidsynth/android/CMakeLists.txt"
}
```

but I have runtime error after I include the library of the first `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Not familiar with android stuff, but can you not make a CMakeLists.txt file that adds the two directories that you have like this: `add_subdirectory(subdir1) add_subdirectory(subdir2)`. In the build.gradle file just list this newly created CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Or just add `add_subdirectory("src/main/cpp/fluidsynth/android/CMakeLists.txt")` to your first CMakeLists.txt and remove the second one from build.gradle?

Comment: @GeorgiGerganov This is worth to be an answer, it fixed my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `add_subdirectory("src/main/cpp/fluidsynth/android/CMakeLists.txt")` to your first CMakeLists.txt and remove the second path from the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: This Fixed my problem, Thanks!